# Okta authentication failing in iOS App with valid details

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, okta

I am trying to authenticate with `Okta` in my iOS app, Create a app is **Okta** dashboard and added client id and redirect url's. After setting up and installing app in simulator. app is throwing the below error:

[image]

Please let me know if i missed any settings.

Created a native app from dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the client ID you're sending in the request is not what you think it is. You should be able to copy the URL from your browser, paste it in something like Notes, and examine the client ID. Make sure it matches what you have in your Okta org and that it doesn't contain any unexpected characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem being faced by every newbie.
Here are some steps which will guide you to make your Okta authentication without error.

1. Create an application in Okta Page.
2. At text field  &  you may put your domain id. ex dev-xxxx.okta.com:/callback
3. Provide the same detail in your okta.plist in iOS Application.

You may refer to the Okta 'GitHub Repositories' for working samples.

Thanks.